# How can I extract the main body of an Orchard Page via a Url

Tags: orchardcms

What I'm looking to do is have 2 views of an orchard page.

The first will include headers and footers, the second just the main body content.

The reason is so that we can maintain the body in one place, and it will be used either as a stand alone site, or just embedded within another.

I'm thinking that it would be done by accessing the page using a different route, or appending a querystring parameter.

Any other options are welcomed.

Comment: Are you talking about an Orchard page made up using Orchards content items? Or your own plain MVC page?

Comment: A page built with the orchard content.

Comment: You'll have to build your own controller.

Comment: Thought so, it's not really an issue, but I thought there might be something that did.  Do you know of any examples on doing this? If so I'll mark them as the answer instead

Comment: In this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338963/routing-a-custom-controller-in-orchard-cms you can check how to implement a custom contoller.

Answer (score 1):

The method I am about to describe is arguably a hack and may go against some of the intentions of the creators of Orchard, but it will get the job done.

Orchard uses the `ThemeFilter` with the `Themed` attribute to decide whether the current controller action's output will be 'themed' --- i.e., be displayed with headers and footers.  The controller used by Orchard to display content items has this attribute enabled, which is why content items are displayed themed.  What you are asking to do is to suppress this 'themed' mode based on the presence of a query string parameter.

`ThemeFilter` kicks in at a very early stage of the page request and applies itself by setting a value in the current request's http context.

ThemeFilter.cs:

```
    public static void Apply(RequestContext context) {
        // the value isn't important
        context.HttpContext.Items[typeof (ThemeFilter)] = null;
    }
```

This class does not provide a way of un`Apply`ing this value.  If you are willing to modify the Orchard source code, you may add this method yourself:

```
    public static void Unapply(RequestContext context) {
        context.HttpContext.Items.Remove(typeof (ThemeFilter));
    }
```

Then you can simply create your own action filter that checks for the existence of a query string and then call this method if appropriate, something like:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Orchard.Mvc.Filters;
using Orchard.Themes;

namespace Demo {
    public class UnthemeFilter : FilterProvider, IActionFilter {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request["unthemed"] != null) {
                ThemeFilter.Unapply(filterContext.RequestContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now by adding `?unthemed=true`, you will be able to suppress the theming.

If you are unwilling or unable to modify the Orchard source code, it is still possible to do the same thing by directly removing the `typeof (ThemeFilter)` from the HTTP context in your filter.  However, this breaks encapsulation and should probably be avoided in object-oriented programming.